# SOAP: Log Payload Request and Response xml

Tags: java, web-services, soap, payload

I want to capture the SOAP request xml and SOAP response xml and dump it in DB as an entire xml format. i use payload for my request and response.

Below is my controller

```
@PayloadRoot(localPart = "StudentDetailsRequest", namespace = TARGET_NAMESPACE)
public @ResponsePayload StudentDetailsResponse getStudentDetails(@RequestPayload StudentDetailsRequest request) throws Exception
{
    StudentDetailsResponse response = new StudentDetailsResponse();
    response=studentService.execute(request);
    return response;
}
```

Please help on how to achieve the same

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked! Below are the steps

```
public String getResponseXML(StudentDetailsResponse response) throws JAXBException
{
     StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(StudentDetailsResponse.class);
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(response,  new StreamResult(sw));
    return sw.toString();
}
```

Comment: also checkout interceptors/handlers for logging